# Re-using zip iterator in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have the `zip` object:

```
L_RANGES = zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21))
```

First call of `L_RANGES` is ok:

```
print(type(L_RANGES))
for a, b in L_RANGES:
  print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
<class 'zip'>
10 11
11 12
12 13
13 14
14 15
15 16
16 17
17 18
18 19
19 20
```

Bu the next calls do not display anything. Is there any way to maintain or reset that. So far I can just convert it to the list:

```
L_RANGES = list(zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21)))
```

Comment: Related: [Can iterators be reset in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3266180)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you were to create a generator each time you loop, that would solve everything, because you could reuse that multiple times. For that, convert `L_RANGES` from a simple generator to a `lambda` creating generators, but don't forget to "call" it each time with `()`:

```
L_RANGES = lambda: zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21))

for a, b in L_RANGES():
  print(a, b)

for a, b in L_RANGES():
  print(a, b)

#works as many times as you want
```

Compared to the other answers this doesn't take up memory (which is the downside of converting to a list) and doesn't require multiple variables for each time you want to loop (by using `tee`) which makes this way more flexible (you can iterate 1000 times if necessary, without creating `L_RANGES_1...L_RANGES_999`) for example:

```
for i in range(1000):
    for a, b in L_RANGES():
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: For an arbitrary number of variables, you would use a dictionary rather than many named variables. But the rest of your answer makes sense.

Comment: Good point @jpp

Answer (score 8):

An iterator, once exhausted, may not be reused. In Python 3.x, `zip` returns an iterator. One solution is to use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to copy an iterator *n* times.

For example, setting `n = 2`, we can do the following:

```
from itertools import tee

L_RANGES_1, L_RANGES_2 = tee(zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21)), 2)

for item in L_RANGES_1:
    # do something

for item in L_RANGES_2:
    # do something else
```

Conversion to a `list` allows use an arbitrary number of times, but is inadvisable for large iterables due to the memory overhead.

For a large number of copies, you can use a dictionary. For example:

```
L_RANGES = dict(zip(range(1000), tee(zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21)), 1000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x `zip()` returns iterator that gets exhausted.

Simplest way to avoid it is:

```
L_RANGES = list(zip(range(10, 20), range(11, 21)))
```