# group disappears in `itertools.groupby` upon calling `list` twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a run-len-encoding in Python using the following code which seem to work

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1, 1, 1]
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a)]
## [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1], [0], [1], [0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

But when I put `g` in an `if` statement, it disappears

```
[list(g) if len(list(g)) > 0 else 0 for k, g in groupby(a)]
## [[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

`k` on the other hand, doesn't seem to be effected by the `if` statement

```
[k if k > 0 and k == 1 else 0 for k, g in groupby(a)]
## [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I need to extract `g` using the `if` statement for some future recording I'm trying to do, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np
[list(np.repeat(1, len(list(g)))) if len(list(g)) > 1 and k == 1 else list(np.repeat(0, len(list(g)))) for k, g in groupby(a)]
```

So my question is why it happens (kind of new to Python) and is there (I'm sure there is) to overcome this

---

**EDIT**

This is not directly related to the question itself, but I've eventually built my `rle/inverse.rle` using a `for` loop over the groups in `groupby`

```
def rle (a):
    indx = 0
    for k, g in groupby(a):
        g_len = len(list(g))
        if g_len == 1 and k == 1:
            a[indx:(indx + g_len)] = [0]
        indx += g_len
```

Comment: Because you exhaust the group-by iterator when you call `list` on it... just turn your list-comprehension into a for-loop and capture the result of the first `list` call with a variable

Comment: It's the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465966/re-using-zip-iterator-in-python-3), but I don't really want to use that as a dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a minimal example:

```
def a():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

b = a()
print(list(b))
print(list(b))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
```

So you can see you can only call `list` on a generator once. You need to assign `list(g)` to a variable first.

Comment: probably, you should explain what an iterator is and note that `itertools.groupby` doesn't return a generator object.